# Is calling rails g controller user multiple times safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I call

```
rails g controller user
```

multiple times to add actions, is this safe?

e.g. I did 'rails g controller user index' but now I want to create more actions?

btw, how can I create all REST based actions automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yesh, safe. See `rails g scaffold` for generating REST actions automatically, including the model and views and tests.

Note that you can also pass a option `--pretend` when running the generator so that it shows you what files will be created, but does not actually create the files.

Answer (score 2):

unless your generating a scaffold then you're probably off better doing it manually anyhow and not using the generator.

In your routes.rb make sure you've got

```
resources :user
```

so now all 7 restful routes will exist (you can check from terminal via `rake routes`) and then just add the methods to your controller as you need them, index, show, new, edit, create, update, delete. Don't forget if you don't want a route to exist you can omit them

```
resources :user, :except => [:index]
```

and vice versa if you only want a few methods

```
resources :user, :only => [:index, :create]
```